# Where do I write an embedded method for my expression in MS Reports?

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I want to create a (vb.net) method and call it from an expression like this:

```
=Code.WhereDoIWriteThiscode(Fields!SomeValue.Value)
```

Where do I write this `WhereDoIWriteThiscode` method ?

The documentation says it is an embedded method, but that does not help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go in `Report > Report Properties`

Then you go in the `Code` tab. You enter this function in the `Custom Code` textbox.